# Show error if data is not posted to an external URL or external URL's server is down

Tags: php

I used the method **POST** to post data to [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) in the case when **data is not sent** or the [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) **server is down** I want to redirect to 404.php I have tried the following code.

```
$sub_req_url = "www.stackoverflow.com";

if (!extension_loaded('curl')) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    include '404.php'; 
    echo "error";
    exit;
        
} else {

    $ch = curl_init($sub_req_url);
    $encoded = '';

    foreach($sendArr as $name => $value) {
        $encoded .= urlencode($name).'='.urlencode($value).'&';
    }

    $encoded = substr($encoded, 0, strlen($encoded)-1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $encoded);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo json_encode($oderid);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where is your code not working or what kind of error are you getting? You should be a little more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the return value of `curl_exec()`. It will be `false` if there was an error.

```
    $ch = curl_init($sub_req_url);
    $encoded = http_build_query($sendArr); // use this instead of your loop

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $encoded);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    if (curl_exec($ch) === false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        include '404.php'; 
        echo "error";
        exit;  
    }      
    curl_close($ch);
    echo json_encode($oderid);
```